# What is meant by finite action signal

Tags: signal-analysis

In section 1.3 from [Signals, Systems and Inference, Alan V. Oppenheim, George C. Verghese](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-011-introduction-to-communication-control-and-signal-processing-spring-2010/readings/MIT6_011S10_notes.pdf). Finite-action signals, which are also called absolutely summable signals, are defined by the condition
\begin{equation}
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|dt<\infty
\end{equation}
whereas for discrete time signal, its as
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}|x[k]|<\infty
\end{equation}
The integration and sum on the left are called the action of the signal. Therefore also known as finite-action signals.
So I would like to know what does **finite action signal** means? Or is there intuitive explanation about it.

Comment: The definition is straightforward, so why go into transformation theory?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? Your description suggests you understand what the definition means. It's simply a signal that has a finite amount of energy.

Answer (score 1):

It's something like *"finite energy signals"*

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|^2 dt<\infty $$

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|x[n]|^2 <\infty $$

except that the "finiteness" is a tougher constraint with

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)| dt<\infty $$

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|x[n]| <\infty $$

for example, the signal

$$ x(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} $$

is *finite energy*, but is not *finite action*.